# Which was the key pressed in HotKeySet function

Tags: autoit

If I have many calls to HotKeySet pointing to the same function, how I know which hotkey called it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @HotKeyPressed variable.

for example:

```
$char = 0
while $char < 126
HotKeySet(Chr ( $char ),"writekeys")
$char = $char + 1
WEnd

while 1
sleep(10)
WEnd


Func writekeys()

HotKeySet(@HotKeyPressed)
send(@HotKeyPressed)
;do something
HotKeySet(@HotKeyPressed,"writekeys")

EndFunc
```